# materialDesign:MahAppsBundledTheme is gone with 5.0.0 release but still works in the Demo project

Tags: material-design-in-xaml

I just updated from to 5.0.0 MD in XAML and realized that `materialDesign:MahAppsBundledTheme` is now erroring out for some reason with *"The name "MahAppsBundledTheme" does not exist in the namespace "http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"*

Checked the DLL version on my side and sure enough it's 5.0.  What could be the reasons?  I only get 2 options: `CustomColorTheme` and `BundledTheme`

```
<Application x:Class="EvolvExpressProductionGuide.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         Startup="App_Startup">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:MahAppsBundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="Indigo" SecondaryColor="Yellow"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/EvolvMaterialDesignDomain;component/Resources/GlobalResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Thanks